# iPhone Mobile Device Management

Tags: iphone, mobile, mdm

I have found a document at
http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_MDM.pdf
says you can develop an application to manage of enterprise iPhones, but it does not give any detail information how it will be.

When I googled I see a few third party solutions, but I would like to implement myself. But I don't know how I can. Are there any documentaion about this or is there anybody experienced about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of this document http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf, there is examples for creating manualy configuration profiles via Apple Script or in C#. When you install iPhone Configuration utility, you can find in the installation folder the dll `iPCUScripting.dll`, the API for creation configuration profiles.

Comment: as i can see it mentions about if the client triggers the request. but i am looking for to send configuration files/install application from server without client request them.

Comment: with the list of clients and informations, you can build automaticaly lot of configuration profiles, and save it on a server.

Comment: ok. how can i send any configuration file to any devices in my firm whenever i want. (although they did not request it). i mean as a system admin, i would like to configure any iphone whenever i want.

Comment: You can send profiles in an email but the user must download it and install it manually. You can't doing automatic installations.

Comment: i've heard that i can send it automaticly if i have an enterprise certificate but how, i do not know.

Comment: The only method I know of is downloading the profileby link / by mail attachment, or direct installation with the phone connected to pc