# How to implement Mobile Device Management in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, mdm

I have gone through a lot of documentation related to **Mobile Device Management** in iOS but still I have a lot of confusion about it.As per the apple they have made a significant change in device management in iOS 7 but still most of the blogs written about it are old and absolute.Can somebody please give me a brief explanation of how I should go step by step in **iOS 7**.Also I want to know if I don't have any MDM server initially then how can I test my code.Is Maverics local server sufficient enough to handle this or we can't process without an MDM server.If it is then please suggest me how should I go.

References:

[iOS: Mobile Device Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744023/ios-mobile-device-management)

[Mobile Device Management with iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066651/mobile-device-management-with-iphone)

[iPhone Mobile Device Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678360/iphone-mobile-device-management)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was NO significant changes between iOS 6 and iOS 7 in MDM protocol. Yes, Apple added additional features, configuration profiles and so on. And usually, they call these things "groundbreaking/revolutionary changes" :)

Actually, the protocol stayed the same (with very minor changes) from version iOS 4.0 to iOS 8.0. I would say the bigest changes were around creation of APNS certificate.

So, you can take any open source implementation of MDM and use it for iOS 7:

- Profile manager (included in OS X Server). it's in some mix of ruby + binary
- [WSO2](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/)
- [iMAS](https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server)

P.S. I would recommend to ask more specific questions. As example, I started to implement MDM server and stuck on item X. I tried Y,Z and it didn't work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: For local testing perspective can I use Mac OSX server?

Comment: I have done it using Maverics server but can you please tell me how can I create my own server.Any suggestion or link would be a great help.

Comment: @Imran: Apple has 150 pages document about MDM protocol, and there is also documentation about OTA protocol (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/OTASecurity/OTASecurity.html) and configuration reference guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iphoneconfigurationprofileref/Introduction/Introduction.html). I would recommend to start from reading all of them and ask specific questions after that.

Comment: Can we use mdm for iOS web apps?

Comment: @Imran: What do you want to do with web apps? Generally speaking, MDM has limited (almost no) notion of webapps.